# Declare var inside if statment and use it in the same if statement condtion

Tags: node.js, variables, if-statement, scope

Using nodejs, I am getting data from an api. That api has limit rate so I am trying to make something that get the limit from header, compare max and current requests if they are equal then don't send request for amount of time, you get the idea.

I was thinking about `if` statement but the variables in the condition are declared inside the request that is inside the if statement itself, like :

```
if (curr > max - 2){
res.send("limit reached");
return;
}
else{
//use request module to get headers from the api and split header to get 
//max and current count of request then declare them to curr and max
//so when someone else call the same request it compare the old vars
// if the statement is false it do the call and get the new vars
//if it is true it make a delay before next request
}
```

i know that is stupid and i sucks in even the basic logic , i don't know ..
if there is a better way to do it can someone point to it . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it straight forward, declare variable `curr` globally(ie. out of all your requests) in your route. Update(Increment) `curr` after every succesful api call in your request. Check your `curr` before every api call, if it exceeds the limit then send error else continue with your call.

The key is that the global variables in nodejs persist throughout the life of your current route .

Assuming you are using express server.
But, if you want to limit your user from making api calls through out the app then prefer using locals(`app.locals`)

Comment: i am getting the rate limit inside the respone header inside the request funciton

Comment: Update the global var or app.locals.var wherever you recieve the limit